# Using prototype javascript to set heading styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, prototype

I'm trying to create H2 headings using prototype so they can be set individually as required.

I'm using `this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));` to add text to the `H2`. I need to use the parent node before `appendChild` which I believe in this case is the `this` keyword but I'm not sure it's being recognised as the parent or if it actually is the parent ? I'm also uncertain as of how to add the text through a parameter  of the constructor itself . I've used a variable 'font' but not sure how to make it work as its not adding a css style ?

I'm learning how to use prototype so if there's any other obvious errors I've missed please let me know.

```
<div id='body'>
<div id='inner'>div here</div>
</div>
<script>
Heading.prototype.font;
Heading.prototype.color;
Heading.prototype.fontSize;
Heading.prototype.headingTxt;
Heading.prototype.setHeading = function() {

   var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
   this.headingTxt = document.createElement('h2');
   this.headingTxt.font = this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
   this.headingTxt.style.color = this.color;
   this.headingTxt.style.fontSize = this.fontSize;
inner.appendChild(headingTxt);
}

function Heading(font, color, fontSize) {

   this.font = font;
   this.color = color;
   this.fontSize = fontSize;
}

var title = new Heading('heading here', 'red', 20);
title.setHeading();

</script>
```

Can anyone help me how can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Which parent node? `this` refers to an instance of `Heading`, i.e. `title`, not to a DOM element.

Comment: Ah clearly using `this` is wrong. I want it to refer to the `H2` element being created as the parent so the text node will be the child.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working version that I stripped down:

```
function Heading(font, color, fontSize) {
   this.font = font;
   this.color = color;
   this.fontSize = fontSize;
}

Heading.prototype.setHeading = function() {
   var inner = document.getElementById('header'); //make sure inner exists
   this.headingTxt = document.createElement('h2'); //you could also scope this to be local with var if you want it to be private 
   inner.appendChild(this.headingTxt);
}

var title = new Heading('heading here', 'red');
title.setHeading();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to reuse the instance the use prototype would be correct. But ideally you would have more to do with it afterwards, like change the values later:

```
(function (window, undefined) {

    window.Heading = (function () {

        var Heading = function (text, fontColor, fontSize, element) {

            // Re-enforce instance
            if (!(this instanceof Heading))
                return new Heading(text, fontColor, fontSize, element);

            // Validate Element. element can be null
            element = (element.nodeType) ? element : null;

            // Get first H2 element in the page if not element is informed
            if (element === null) {

                var h2 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('H2');

                if (h2.length)
                    // Get first H2 element from the page
                    element = h2[0];

            } else if (element.nodeType !== 1)

                // Validate if this is an Element
                throw new Error('Only Element type is accepted.');

            this._element = element;
            this._fontColor = fontColor;
            this._fontSize = fontSize;
            this._text = text;
        };

        Heading.prototype.set = function () {

            var propertyName = (this._element.textContent) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

            this._element[propertyName] = this._text;
            this._element.style.fontSize = this._fontSize;
            this._element.style.color = this._fontColor;

            return this;
        };

        Heading.prototype.values = function (text, fontColor, fontSize) {

            this._fontColor = fontColor;
            this._fontSize = fontSize;
            this._text = text;

            return this;
        };

        return Heading;

    })();

})(window);

// Example
var instance = Heading('First exmaple', 'red', '20px');

// Set
instance.set();

// Re-use
instance.values('Second example', 'blue').set();
```

If you don't need to re-use the instance, a simple function might be appropriate.

```
var Heading = function (text, fontColor, fontSize, element) {

    // Validate Element. element can be null
    element = (element.nodeType) ? element : null;

    // Get first H2 element in the page if not element is informed
    if (element === null) {

        var h2 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('H2');

        if (h2.length)
            // Get first H2 element from the page
            element = h2[0];

    } else if (element.nodeType !== 1)

        // Validate if this is an Element
        throw new Error('Only Element type is accepted.');

    var propertyName = (element.textContent) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

    element[propertyName] = text;
    element.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    element.style.color = fontColor;
};
```